# How to get bound `this` and closed variables?

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to get whatever's bound to `this` and all the closed-over variables out of a function?

e.g.

```
 function f() { console.log(this); }
 let x = f.bind(7);
 function g() { console.log(x); }
```

1. Is it possible to extract that `7` from `x`?
2. `g` closes over `x`. Is it possible to get array of closed-over variables from `g`?

Comment: No you can't (unless the function's behavior exposes it of course), and no you can't.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Is it possible to extract that `7` from `x`?

Nope. `f` would have to explicitly give you a way to retrieve `this` (for instance, `function f() { return this; }`). Since it doesn't, you can't.

In specification terms, you're asking if it's possible to retrieve the value of the [[BoundThis]] internal slot from a function. [[BoundThis]] only appears three times in the spec: Where [bound function exotic objects](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects) are described, where their [[[Call]] internal operation](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-bound-function-exotic-objects-call-thisargument-argumentslist) is described, and where the [process of creating them](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-boundfunctioncreate) is outlined. So, not in an operation allowing you to retrieve the value.

> `g` closes over `x`. Is it possible to get array of closed-over variables from `g`?

Nope. :-) Which is a good thing in terms of having private information and a public API to it.

Providing that would require a means of accessing the list of bindings in the [lexical environment](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-lexical-environments) object attached to `g` and all of its outer lexical environments. There's none in the specification.

---

There's no *specification* reason either or both couldn't be added, but I think (and this is just my personal speculation) that TC39 (the committee that decides these things) would be a hard sell on the first and a nearly impossible sell on the second (which has massive, and negative, implementation impacts).